# Join datatables with LINQ, select multiple columns and sums with group by multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable, group-by

I am joining two datatables with LINQ and trying to select data from both tables, including sum of one column grouped by two  columns. The data structure seems like this.

```
table1 (Demands)
  propertyID
  propertyGroupID
  supplierID
  demand

propertyID  |propertyGroupID    |supplierId |demand |ContractId
13          |3                  |3          |2      |1
22          |4                  |3          |1      |1
21          |5                  |3          |12     |1
15          |5                  |3          |3      |1
16          |7                  |3          |16     |1
23          |5                  |3          |5      |1


table2 (Supplies)
  supplierID
  propertyID
  supply

supplierId  |propertyID |supply
4           |23         |2764
1           |22         |3521
1           |16         |2533
11          |23         |876
4           |21         |5668
```

I would like to have the result as

```
supplierID
propertyGroupID
sum(supply)
sum(demand)
```

These would be grouped by supplierID and propertyGroupID. So, finally I would like to compare actual supplies to the demand by each supplier and property group.

What I have done so far is

```
var result = from demandItems in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join supplyItems in table2.AsEnumerable() on
Convert.ToInt16(demandItems["propertyID"]) equals 
Convert.ToInt16(supplyItems["propertyID"])
             group new
             {
                demandItems,
                supplyItems
            }
            by new
            {
                Supplier = supplyItems.Field<string>("supplierID"),
                PropertyGroup = demandItems.Field<int>("propertyGroupID")
            }
            into groupDt
             select new
             {
                SupplierID = groupDt.Key.Supplier,
                PropertyGroupId = groupDt.Key.PropertyGroup,
                SumOfSupply = groupDt.Sum(g => g.supplyItems.Field<double>("supply")),
            SumOfDemand = groupDt.Sum(g => g.demandItems.Field<double>("demand"))
        };
```

This works fine and I get correct sum of supply grouped by different suppliers and property groups. However, the sum of demand is not correct.

```
SupplierID  |PropertyGroupID    |SumOfSupply    |SumOfDemand
4           |5                  |8432           |17
1           |4                  |3521           |1
1           |7                  |2533           |16
11          |5                  |876            |5
```

As you see, table1 has only one supplier (ID=3). The correct result data should be

```
SupplierID  |PropertyGroupID    |SumOfSupply    |SumOfDemand
4           |5                  |8432           |0
1           |4                  |3521           |0
1           |7                  |2533           |0
11          |5                  |876            |0
3           |3                  |0              |2
3           |4                  |0              |1              
3           |5                  |0              |20
3           |7                  |0              |16
```

How to obtain the result I want?

EDIT 2018-01-05

I'm using NetMage's solution to solve my problem. However, I get an error message from

```
var result = from d in table1sum.Concat(table2sum)...
```

Error   CS1929  'EnumerableRowCollection<>' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Concat<>(IQueryable<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<>'

Is this propably due to the fact that my original tables are actually read from database?

```
DataTable table1 = DemandDataSet.Tables[0];
DataTable table2 = SupplyDataSet.Tables[0];
```

For example, I had to use notation

```
var table1sum = table1.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new
            { propertyGroupID = (int)d["propertyGroupID"],
            supplierId = (int)d["supplierId"],
            demand = (double)d["demand"],
            supply = 0 });
```

Edit 2 2018-01-05

The error was due to type differences between fields in tables table1sum and table2sum. Specifically, fields "supply" and "demand" had different types in comparing tables. When I changed

```
demand = 0.0
```

and

```
supply = 0.0
```

compiler found .Concat -method.

Comment: Why are you joining on `propertyID`? I think you need some sample data that shows what happens when `table1` has a `SupplierID` also in `table2`.

Comment: PropertyID is the connection to propertyGroup. Table2 doesn't have information on propertyGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data tables are not normalized, which I think is causing your issue. You don't really want to combine the supply and demand tables.

First, summarize the demand table to the information needed for the result:

```
var table1sum = table1.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new { d.propertyGroupID, d.supplierId, d.demand, supply = 0 });
```

Second, summarize the supply table to the information needed for the result, using the demand table to get the `propertyGroupID` needed:

```
var table2sum = from supplyItem in table2.AsEnumerable()
                join demandItem in table1.AsEnumerable() on supplyItem.propertyID equals demandItem.propertyID
                select new {
                    demandItem.propertyGroupID,
                    supplyItem.supplierId,
                    demand = 0,
                    supplyItem.supply
                };
```

Now you can combine the summaries and group to get the desired result:

```
var result = from d in table1sum.Concat(table2sum)
             group d by new { d.supplierId, d.propertyGroupID } into dg
             select new {
                 SupplierID = dg.Key.supplierId,
                 PropertyGroupId = dg.Key.propertyGroupID,
                 SumOfSupply = dg.Sum(g => g.supply),
                 SumOfDemand = dg.Sum(g => g.demand)
             };
```